# Populate 'Multi Select' parameter ('Extended Choice Parameter' plugin) in Jenkins dynamically

Tags: git, groovy, jenkins

Is there a way in Jenkins to dynamically populate 'Multi Select' parameter?

To describe my issue in detail: We use Git and i would like to retrieve list of repositories present in Git as soon as i click on 'Build with Parameters' button as shown below:

[image]

I have gone through several links but none of them seem to answer what i am looking for. I know i can schedule a cron which would list down the repositories in a file and then with the help of 'Extended Choice Parameter' plugin, 'Multi Select' parameter will automatically populate *but* i am looking for a way that does not involve using an external script; everything should happen through Jenkins and with a single job. Groovy looks like the tool but i am not sure. Any suggestion?

Using Perl for my build script & Jenkins ver. is 1.547

Answer (score 0):

Would the [Git parameter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Parameter+Plugin) do what you are looking for?

You might also look at the [Extended Choice Parameter Script plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extended+Choice+Parameter+Script+plugin), [Extensible Choice Parameter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extensible+Choice+Parameter+plugin), or [Jenkins Dynamic Parameter Plug-in](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Dynamic+Parameter+Plug-in). For more inspiration look at [Jenkins plugin page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins).

Comment: 'Extended Choice Parameter Script plugin' might would have helped but there is no link to download it. It doesn't show up in the 'Available Plugins' tab in `Jenkins > Plugin Manager` section. :(

Comment: Couldn't find the actual plugin either. But found the following comment on the page:
While this plugin is an excellent idea, note that the "normal" [https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extended+Choice+Parameter+plugin] does provide a workaround way of executing a script: Since the ECPP does support using an http URL as property file source, you can point it to a cgi-script that'll create the parameter values on demand. (just have the CGI script return text/plain and the content of the properties file)